# Firebase OrderbyChild Query returns the parent key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a problem retrieve and delete the correct level of the node in Firebase database using the `orderByChild().equalTo()` method.

Searched over the web for quite a while and didn't really solve my problem. Please help.

**My database structure:**

[image]

**My Firebase methods to add and delete photo**

```
private void addPhotoToDatabase(String url){
    Log.d(TAG, "addPhotoToDatabase: adding photo to database");

    String newPhotoKey = myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_photos)).push().getKey();
    Photo photo = new Photo();
    photo.setDate_created(getTimeStamped());
    photo.setImage_path(url);
    photo.setUser_id(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    photo.setPhoto_id(newPhotoKey);

    //insert into database.
    myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_photos)).child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(newPhotoKey).setValue(photo);

}

private void deletePhotoFromDatabase(String image_path){
    Log.d(TAG, "deletePhotoFromDatabase: deleting photo from database");
    Log.d(TAG, "deletePhotoFromDatabase: image_path is " + image_path);

    String user_id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_photos))
            .child(user_id)
            .orderByValue().equalTo(image_path).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String photoKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: photo key is " + photoKey);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

I know I don't have a `removeValue` or `setValue(null)` method yet because I just can't get to the correct level. The photoKey I was trying to retrieve is the `-L-FnLvNxLauiue4InSxE` which was automatically generated when adding into Firebase. However, the log always returns to its parent node which is the `UID`.

By the way, the image_path I retrieved from the Firebase storage which was logged correctly.

Could someone give me some inspirations where I did wrong? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
 myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_photos))
        .child(user_id)
        .orderByValue().equalTo(image_path)
```

to this:

```
 DatabaseReference myRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
 myRef.child("user_photos").child(user_id).orderByChild("photo_id").equalTo(image_path);
```

Im assuming `user_photos` is a direct child under root, thus using the above `myRef`

Edit:

```
 @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnaphot.getChildren()){

            String photoKey = data.getKey();
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: photo key is " + photoKey);

    } }
```

Comment: Thanks. I have just tried this. It still logged the photoKey as the UID. Could it be a problem of the way I add the photo object into the database?

Comment: and yes, user_photos node is under root. and myRef is the as you suggested to be.

Comment: check the edit, you have to loop inside of the onDataChange